# Syntax question about ES6 classes (constructor/super)

Tags: javascript

As this example is copy/pasted from inline  tags in my html file, the formatting may be off.

Anyhow, I'm new to JS and have a syntax question. This example is from an MDN basics of JS article. Here is a simple shape class:

```
class Shape {
  constructor(name, sides, sideLength) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sides = sides;
    this.sideLength = sideLength;
  }
  calcPerimeter() {
    console.log(this.sides * this.sideLength);
  }
}
```

Then, I want to extend it with a Square class

```
class Square extends Shape {
  constructor(name, sides, sideLength) {
    super(name, sides, sideLength);
  }
  calcArea() {
    console.log(this.sideLength * this.sideLength);
  } 
}
```

Now, this is obviously a bit silly. It's a Square class, so the name should always be "square", and it should always have 4 sides. We can remove the name and sides parameters.

```
class Square extends Shape {
  constructor(sideLength) {
    super(sideLength);
    this.name = "square;
    this.sides = 4;
  }
  calcArea() {
    console.log(this.sideLength * this.sideLength);
  } 
}
```

The problem is this doesn't work, and I'm not sure why. I would think I could now do let square = new Square(5); but sideLength is undefined. If I explicitly set this.sideLength to sideLength in Square class, it fixes the problem, but then I'm not inheriting anything from Shape class. What's wrong with my syntax here? How do I do what I'm trying to do (inherit sideLengths from Shape)?

Answer (score 2):

To follow the inheritance hierarchy, you need to call the super constructor with the values from the child constructor. You do not need to assign new properties to `this` instead you can pass the properties for the `Square` using the `super(...)` call:

```js
class Shape {
  constructor(name, sides, sideLength) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sides = sides;
    this.sideLength = sideLength;
  }
  calcPerimeter() {
    console.log(this.sides * this.sideLength);
  }
}

class Square extends Shape {
  constructor(sideLength) {
    super("square", 4, sideLength);
  }
  calcArea() {
    console.log(this.sideLength * this.sideLength);
  } 
}

const square = new Square(5);
square.calcArea();
```

When you do not pass the properties `name` and `sides` to the parent constructor and only pass `sidelength`, the `name` gets initialized with the value of `sidelength` due to the position of the parameter in the parent constructor:

```
constructor(sideLength) {
     super(sideLength);
     this.name = "square";
     this.sides = 4;
}
```

Makes the call to the parent constructor like so:

```
Shape(sidelength, undefined, undefined)
```

So as the last parameter which is `sidelength` becomes `undefined`, when you try to call the `calcArea` it does not work.

Comment: Holy crap, this is so obvious now that you point it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
super(sideLength);
```

This calls the parent constructor with one argument, the `sideLength`. So, this runs:

```
  constructor(name, sides, sideLength) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sides = sides;
    this.sideLength = sideLength;
  }
```

which turns into, since only the first argument, `name`, has a value in it:

```
this.name = sideLengthPassedFromSquare;
this.sides = undefined;
this.sideLength = undefined;
```

IF you want to be able to omit properties passed like this, have the super constructor either list the required properties first (like `sideLength`):

```
  constructor(sideLength, name, sides) {
```

Or pass a single object instead:

```
constructor({ name, sides, sideLength }) {
```

and do

```
super({ sideLength })
```

Comment: That's clever to put the required properties first. I don't understand how passing a single object works though, could you elaborate on that? I tried to just add curly braces around my parameters as you have and I got a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'undefined' as it is undefined."

Comment: If you get that error, it sounds like you didn't pass anything to the `super` call. A single object is useful because it'll let you list only the properties you want without having to rely on the argument order in the superclass.